# Combining a Regex and a known String

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Here is my current code:

```
exp1 = re.compile('((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{4})')
```

But what I want to implement is something like this:

```
regMonth = '(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)'
exp1 = re.compile(r'(regMonth'+ r'\s?\d{4})')
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
regMonth = 'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec'
pattern = r'(?i)(?:' + regMonth + r')\s?\d{4}'
```

Like so:

```
regMonth = 'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec'

string_1 = 'Jan 1947, dec 3456'

pattern = r'(?i)(?:' + regMonth + r')\s?\d{4}'

y = re.findall(pattern, string_1)
```

If you print `y` in this case, you get:

```
['Jan 1947', 'dec 3456']
```

Which is an array of the matched dates. `string_1` is the input string, which contains the date in the desired format.

---

## Explanation -

First off, you can interpret `pattern` to be:

```
pattern = r'(?i)(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s?\d{4}'
```

Where:

```
(?i) - Indicates that the regex is case-insensitive (If you want the user to enter the Month with the first letter being in caps, then remove this)
(?:  - Is a non-capturing group containing the month (followed by 'regMonth')
```

---

**Note -** You must put the second string `')\s?\d{4}'` as a **raw-string** also, otherwise the whole thing gets messed up.

Also, the non-capturing group is important, otherwise the regex will match `Jan`, 'Feb', ... , `Nov`, or `Dec\s?\d{4}`.
Hence, `Dec\s?\d{4}` becomes a completely separate option, which is undesirable.

Comment: yes, I tried that and worked well,thank you for your response.